ASP.NET MVC 5 : Request.isAuthenticated always returns true after host app on web server
I am using Identity authentication, the app and the code in razor view works correctly when executed in Visual Studio 2015, but after publishing and hosting the application on Smarterasp host, the following condition always returns true:
@if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
{
    var UserID = User.Identity.GetUserId();
    var CurrentUser = db.Users.Where(a => a.Id == UserID).SingleOrDefault();
    <h1>@CurrentUser.FirstName</h1>
}

and shows error as the CurrentUser is null.
Can you please help me?
I am trying to make the code work correctly in the development environment, and for the user authentication to be verified, and for the condition to be output true

''' @if (Request.IsAuthenticated) {
var UserID = User.Identity.GetUserId(); var CurrentUser = db.Users.Where(a => a.Id == UserID).SingleOrDefault(); } ''' problem is isAuthenticated always true –

Theoretically it might use Windows authentication in production environment. What does ((ClaimsIdentity)User.Identity).AuthenticationType return?
